# Using Octave built-in function mldivide in C++ API

Tags: c++, matlab, octave

I am programming in C++ and want to use the powerful built-in functions in Octave. I followed the [standalone program](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Standalone-Programs.html)guideline on Octave website. I can run the function norm (which is called as Fnorm in C++) with the sample code successfully. Now I want to use the function mldivide to solve a linear equation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/builtin-defun-decls.h>

octave_value_list input;
octave_value_list retval;

int main (void) {

Matrix A(4,4);

for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   for (octave_idx_type j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    A(i,j) = 1.0 / (static_cast<double> (i) +static_cast<double> ( j ) + 1.0 ) ;

    ColumnVector b(4,1.0);
    input.append(A);
    input.append(b);

    retval=Fmldivide(input);
    ColumnVector x =retval(0).column_vector_value();

    std::cout << "A = " << std::endl << A << std::endl
              << "b = " << std::endl << b << std::endl
              << "x = " << std::endl << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

But there are errors as follow.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:23:26: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const octave_value_list&' from expression of type 'Matrix'

In file included from main.cpp:3:0:

/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/include/octave-3.8.0/octave/../octave/builtin-defun-decls.h:198:1: error: in passing argument 1 of 'octave_value_list Fmldivide(const octave_value_list&, int)'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why this is not working:

1. [`Fmldivide`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d4/d05/data_8cc.html#acf094020d4951303dfc5df0055f0ef36) takes an [`octave_value_list`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d6/db6/classoctave__value__list.html) as input
2. `Fmldivide` returns an `octave_value_list` but you are declaring a [`ColumnVector`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d0/d25/classColumnVector.html)

You can fix the first by:

1. converting your input into a single [`octave_value`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d3/d35/classoctave__value.html) and leaving the conversion to `octave_value_list` to the compiler:

   Fmldivide (octave_value (b), 1);
2. use `do_binary_op` with the left division operator:

   do_binary_op (octave_value::op_ldiv, b, 1);

You can fix the second by using the `column_vector_value` method:

1. if you are using `Fmldivide` you get a list, so you must index the first element first:

   ColumnVector x = Fmldivide (b, 1)(0).column_vector_value ();
2. if you use `do_binary_op` you will get an `octave_value` so indexing is unecessary:

   ColumnVector x = do_binary_op (octave_value::op_ldiv, b, 1).column_vector_value ();

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer. Actually I made a mistake in code which should be Fmldivide (A,b), where A is the matrix and b is the vector. But the Fmldivide requires arguments as: octave_value_list Fmldivide(const octave_value_list & args,
int). What is the args here and what does the integer represent here?

Comment: @Jeremy take a look at the source of [`Fmldivide`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d4/d05/data_8cc_source.html#l05612). There's some pre-processor black magic going there (`DEFUN`) which must be handling the rest of the arguments. I don't know what the int is for but you can forget about it. The first input, `args`, is an octave_value_list with all of the input that Octave's `mldivide` function would take, i.e., x and y.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to input the argument as octave_value(A,b), but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Jeremy I think you misunderstood how it works. `octave_value_list` and `octave_value` are different things. Take a  look at the constructors for `octave_value_list`. In your case, seems like you better off initializaing one with with `A`, and then appending `b` to it.

Comment: I modified the code as your suggestion above. But it stills shows Segmentation fault: 11. It seems the input.append just appends the matrix A, and it cannot include the vector b in it.